# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, synchronization

I have synced data where I attach some products to another one as related ones, save and sync method works just fine, **my issue in edit part**.

I get this error when I try to load my product edit page:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'product_relatives' (SQL: select `product_relatives`.*, `product_relatives`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id`, `product_relatives`.`relatives_id` as `pivot_relatives_id` from `product_relatives` inner join `product_relatives` on `product_relatives`.`id` = `product_relatives`.`relatives_id` where `product_relatives`.`product_id` = 49)
```

## Codes

`this is my edit function`

```
public function edit($id)
    {
      $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
      //another synced data and how i retrieve them
      $suboptions = Suboption::all();
      $suboptions2 = array();
      foreach($suboptions as $suboption) {
        $suboptions2[$suboption->id] = $suboption->title;
      }

      // my issue comes from here
      $relatives = ProductRelative::all();
      $relatives2 = array();
      foreach($relatives as $relative) {
        $relatives2[$relative->id] = $relative->title;
      }

      return view('admin.products.edit', compact('product','suboptions2', 'relatives2'));
    }
```

`blade code`

```
{{ Form::label('relatives', 'Relative Products') }}

{{Form::select('relatives[]', $relatives2, null, ['class' => 'form-control tagsselector', 'multiple' => 'multiple'])}}
```

`product model`

```
public function relatives()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(ProductRelative::class, 'product_relatives', 'product_id', 'relatives_id');
  }
```

`relatives model`

```
public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'product_relatives';

    public $fillable = ['product_id', 'relatives_id'];


    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
```

any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your models.  What you've shown to be the relatives model looks a lot like a model you've created for the pivot.  At least based on the table name and fillable fields of the relatives model.

Comment: @MMMTroy is all about `product` model, in my `ProductRelative` model I get `product_id` and `relatives_id` which is id of another product. my `product_relatives` table is just handling relation between products will not add any values to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL statement that is failing makes perfect sense.  It is attempting to join the table product_relatives to the product_relatives table.  So the error `Not unique table or alias` being thrown makes sense based on the query alone.

The next step is to try and think of reasons Laravel might be getting mixed up here.

Since you are trying to create a belongsToMany with the same model, you'll need these tables

1. products
2. product_relatives

Now, you only need to create one model:

1. Product

Your Product model should contain:

```
public function relatives()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_relative', 'product_id', 'relative_id');
}
```

Your ProductRelative model should contain:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
}
public function relative()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'relatives_id');
}
```

The issue was happening because you were using the ProductRelative model as a pivot table, and tried to create a BelongsToMany relationship within it using the same table name as the model itself.

Comment: error stays the same, `PS` i do not have 3 tables i only have 2 tables, `products` & `product_relatives`, `product_relatives` only stores id of products so will say `product id 1` is related to `product id 20` that's all. it only stores id's of products in different columns

Comment: Then you shouldn't be doing a belongsToMany relationship.  It implies using a pivot table between two models.

Comment: At this point I'm lacking a bit of context to make suggestions to database design.  Normally to create a relationship between two models though you would use a HasMany relationship.  The confusing part to me is your $fillable fields.  Those look like you are trying to create a pivot table.

Comment: so what if i make my products model `hasMany` relatives and `relatives` model `belongsTo`?

Comment: In that case your Relatives model would contain the product_id.  So it can only "belongTo" a single product.  Several Relatives can "belongTo" the same product however, so from the Products perspective it is "HasMany".  Does this sound like what your are looking for?  Otherwise, if you are wanting Relatives to HaveMany products, and Products to HaveMany Relatives, then you wanted a BelongsToMany, which I've described in my answer.

Comment: ok i changed my models to: product `return $this->hasMany(ProductRelative::class);` relative `return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);` and it returning result as i wish in edit page, but when i hit save i get this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync()` on `$product->relatives()->sync($request->relatives);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170505/discussion-between-mmmtroy-and-mafortis).